# How to delete multiple entities using Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony 2.8 based project to manage contact. The user can select from a list any number of contacts and should be able to delete all selected contacts at once. How can this be done in a single Query Builder statement?

```
// Contact entity uses a GUID as ID
$guids = array(...);

try {
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();  

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->delete('AppBundle:Contact', 'c')                
        ->where('c.guid in (:guids)')
        ->setParameter(':guids', array($guids, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY));

    log($qb->getSql());
    $qb->execute();

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();            
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // Rollback the transaction
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();
}
```

**1. Problem**

Addressing the entity with `AppBundle:Contact` (which works without any problem when building a `SELECT` statement) does not work. This is the log output:

```
Query: DELETE FROM AppBundle:Contact c WHERE c.guid in (:guids)
Exception: Doctrine\DBAL\SQLParserUtilsException: Value for :Contact not found in params array. Params array key should be "Contact" in
```

**2. Problem**

Using the table name instead (`->delete('contact', 'c')`) does not work as well:

```
Query: DELETE FROM contact c WHERE c.guid in (:guids)
Exception: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c WHERE c.guid in ('Array')'
```

**3. Problem**

Deleting a single entity does not work either:

```
->delete('contact', 'c')                
->where('c.guid = (:guid)')
->setParameter(':guid', $guids[0]);

Query: DELETE FROM contact c WHERE c.guid = :guid
Exception: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c WHERE c.guid = 'E7516B91-0549-4FFB-85F2-4BD03DC3FFC1''
```

**What might be wrong her?**

Comment: To start with, $em->getConnection->createQueryBuilder returns a completely different class of object as opposed to $em->createQueryBuilder().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1st. Problem.** Change setParameter line to the following, you don't need to use : in name of param.

```
->setParameter('guids', $guids);
```

**Second problem** - you should not use real table name if you're dealing with queryBuilder.

**Third problem** - your logic is not correct. If you want to delete single then

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete('AppBundle:Contact', 'c')                
    ->where('c.guid = :guid')
    ->setParameter('guid', $guids[0]);
```

**Additionally**

I don't really know what doctrine version you're using, but

`$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()` - seems wrong, because usually you're getting connection if you want to execute RAW SQL.

Try to change to

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
```

And you need to use brackets around the variable only if it's array. Check code below

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere('r.id IN (:ids)')
             ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

Answer (score 7):

Unless you want to execute raw SQL, you don't have to use your entity manager's connection, so you can replace `$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()` by 
`$em->createQueryBuilder()`

You could do something like

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete('AppBundle:Contact', 'c')                
    ->where('c.guid in (:guids)')
    ->setParameter(':guids', $guids);
```

And if you want to log/execute it

```
$query = $qb->getQuery();
log($query->getSql());
$query->execute();
```

You also don't need to add the `beginTransaction` and `rollback`, if the query fails and an exception is thrown, doctrine will rollback automatically.